# Google Form Script - Email Submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get google to email me the submitted information from a form.  I can get it to work with the default sheet (Form Responses)  But I'm using a seperate sheet called "ConversionTracker" that actually uses the query function to import the data from the default sheet to the second sheet so I can use formulas within the responses.  Basically I want the email script to reference the second sheet rather than the first sheet when it sends the email of the last submission.. Every time I use the script I have it sends the data from the first sheet (Form Responses) Rather than Sheet named "Conversion Tracker"  I've tried different variations of the script but I can't seem to get it.  See script below.

```
function Initialize() {

 try {

var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

for (var i in triggers)
  ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);

ScriptApp.newTrigger("EmailGoogleFormData")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onFormSubmit().create();

 } catch (error) {
throw new Error("Please add this code in the Google Spreadsheet");
 }
 }

  function EmailGoogleFormData(e) {

if (!e) {
  throw new Error("Please go the Run menu and choose Initialize");
}

  try {

if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) {


  // You may replace this with another email address
  var email = "dustin.****@b****.com";

  // Enter your subject for Google Form email notifications
  var subject = "Google Form Submitted";

  var key, entry,
    message = "",
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
    sheet = ss.getSheets()["ConversionTracker"],
    ss.setActiveSheet(sheet),
    cols = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  // Iterate through the Form Fields
  for (var keys in cols) {

    key = cols[keys];
    entry = e.namedValues[key] ? e.namedValues[key].toString() : "";

    // Only include form fields that are not blank
    if ((entry !== "") && (entry.replace(/,/g, "") !== ""))
      message += key + ' :: ' + entry + "\n\n";
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
}
 } catch (error) {
   Logger.log(error.toString());
 }
   }
```

**The script that works and sends the data from the first sheet is:**

> function Initialize() {
>       try {
>
> ```
> var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
>
> for (var i in triggers)
>   ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
>
> ScriptApp.newTrigger("EmailGoogleFormData")
>   .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
>   .onFormSubmit().create();
> } catch (error) {
> throw new Error("Please add this code in the Google Spreadsheet");   } }   function EmailGoogleFormData(e) {
> if (!e) {
> throw new Error("Please go the Run menu and choose Initialize");   }
> try {
>
> if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) {
>
>   // You may replace this with another email address
>   var email = "dustin****@b****.com";
>
>   // Enter your subject for Google Form email notifications
>   var subject = "Google Form Submitted";
>
>   var key, entry,
>     message = "",
>     ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
>     cols = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
>
>   // Iterate through the Form Fields
>   for (var keys in cols) {
>
>     key = cols[keys];
>     entry = e.namedValues[key] ? e.namedValues[key].toString() : "";
>
>     // Only include form fields that are not blank
>     if ((entry !== "") && (entry.replace(/,/g, "") !== ""))
>       message += key + ' :: ' + entry + "\n\n";
>   }
>
>   MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
> }   } catch (error) {
> Logger.log(error.toString());   } }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can use text inside the square brackets to get the sheet:

```
sheet = ss.getSheets()["ConversionTracker"]
```

I'd use the `.getSheetByName()` method.

```
getSheetByName("ConversionTracker");
```

The code:

```
ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ConversionTracker");
```

Comment: Hi,  I get the message in the log " [15-10-27 12:09:01:639 EDT] TypeError: Cannot find function getSheetByName in object Sheet."  when I try changing that.  see below the code I changed to.. 

var key, entry,
    message = "",
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
    sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ConversionTracker");
    ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
    var cols = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

Comment: You are using a variable named `ss`, which typically is used for the *spreadsheet*.  But you are assigning the active sheet to the variable `ss`.  Use `ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`

Comment: Hi sandy,  I'm getting the error message with that as well " [15-10-27 10:10:10:559 PDT] InternalError: Cannot find method setActiveSheet((class))."  My script is:     var key, entry,
    message = "",
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
    sheet = ss.getSheets()["ConversionTracker"];
    ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
    var cols = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

Comment: You still have `sheet = ss.getSheets()["ConversionTracker"]; ` in your code.  Add this line of code `Logger.log('sheet: ' + sheet);'  somewhere after the line of code to assign `sheet`.  Run the code, then in the **View** menu, open **Logs**.   What is printed to the Logs?

Comment: Hi Sandy, I think maybe my ; and , aren't right.. But I did the logger like you said it says: [15-10-27 13:42:57:877 EDT] sheet: Sheet
[15-10-27 13:42:58:086 EDT] InternalError: Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number).  I changed the [ ] so they're not there anymore so now the code is: ` var key, entry,
    message = "",
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
    sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ConversionTracker");
    Logger.log('sheet: ' + sheet);
    ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
    var cols = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];`

Comment: You are now getting the `sheet` object correctly.  You should also learn how to use the debugger, in order to run each line one at a time.  [Google Documentation - Debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)